# I get an error saying "expected an indented block" and don't know why

Tags: python

Hey I just starting learning python, i'm using the 2.7.
To practice what I've learned so far I decided to write a small script for a coin converter. It was going well until I got this problem. I get an indentation error on line 9, in the elif part. Can you help me figure it out?

```
print "                               Conversor de moeda"
print "                                      by DB \n"

def voltar():
     opcao=raw_input("--------------------------------------------------------------------------\nPara converter outro valor Inserir 1 \nPara voltar ao menu     Inserir 2")
     if opcao == "1":
         #do something
     elif opcao == "2":
         tipo_conv
     else:
         voltar()     
def conversor():
      tipo_conv=raw_input("Inserir o número correspondente ao tipo de conversão desejado e carregar no enter: \n1 - Euros -> Dólares  \n2 - Dólares -> Euros \n3 - Euros -> Libras  \n4 - Libras -> Euros \n")

      if tipo_conv == "1":
          qtd=input("Inserir quantidade de Euros a converter:")
          qtd2=qtd * 1.09212
          print qtd, "Euros =" , qtd2, "Dólares"
          voltar()
      elif tipo_conv == "2":
          qtd=input("Inserir quantidade de Dólares a converter:")
          qtd2=qtd * 0.915650
          print qtd, "Dólares =" , qtd2, "Euros"
          voltar()
      elif tipo_conv == "3":
          qtd=input("Inserir quantidade de Euros a converter:")
          qtd2=qtd * 0.751910 
          print qtd, "Euros =" , qtd2, "Libras"
          voltar()
      elif tipo_conv == "4":
          qtd=input("Inserir quantidade de Libras a converter:")
          qtd2=qtd * 1.32995
          print qtd, "Libras =" , qtd2, "Euros"
          voltar()
      else:
          print "Erro. Escolher uma das quatro opções disponíveis"
          conversor()

conversor()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to write an `if` statement without any executable code use the `pass` keyword. This indicates that you will write some code in the block at a later stage.

```
if opcao == "1":
    pass
elif opcao == "2":
    ......
```

Your program should then run.

Comment: Also `...` works, but `pass` is preferable. Also, it doesn't only mean you write some code later, it can legitimately mean the block does nothing.